React Native 0.74.2 yarn lifecycle method is not called after running 'yarn install'
How to call lifecycle events of 'yarn install' on react native 0.74.2 and yarn version is 3.6.4
I've added yarn lifecycle methods in my package.json under the scripts section. However, when I run the command 'yarn install', the following lifecycle methods are not being called.
"preinstall": "echo 'preinstall'",
"install": "echo 'install'",
"postinstall": "echo 'postinstall'",
"prepublish": "echo 'prepublish'",
% yarn --version : 3.6.4
React Native 0.74.2 yarn lifecycle method is not called after running 'yarn install'
Yarn

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
